# jquery sortable() lets drag&drop header

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using jQuery sortable() function to allow user to drag and drop rows of the table. The table itself is pretty standard, looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in Javascript file I have:

```
$('table tbody').sortable()
```

which works great, except the fact that it makes header draggable, I can sort it as well as other rows. How can I fix this issue and make header static?

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the header from the plugin:

Give a class to the header `tr`

```
<table>
    <tr class="header-tr">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then:

```
$('table tr').sortable({items: 'tr:not(.header-tr)'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this attribute to your sortable

```
$(table).sortable({

            helper: "clone",
            axis: "x",

            revert: 100,
            distance: 0,
            forceHelperSize: true,
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            scrollSensitivity: 0,
            start: function(event, ui){
                ui.placeholder.width(ui.helper.width());
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {

            },
             cancel: '.nondraggable',

            change: function (e, ui) { 
                console.log("sort called");
            },
            tolerance: "pointer"
        });
```

Comment: simply add $(table).sortable({cancel:'nondraggable'})

Answer (score 0):

here html is not good

```
<thead> <tbody>
```

look [thead](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp)

this work

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John1</td>
        <td>Doe1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```